# Is naming an index required?

Tags: mysql, index

I am a little bit confused about **naming** an index if it's required or not. In `stackoverflow` and here, I saw adding an index like this: (through coding)

```
    ADD INDEX index_name (column_name, ...)
    //whether a per-column or multiple-column index
```

But, when I tried to add an `index` using `phpMyadmin` interface, I got this:

[image]

As you can see there is no `name` while adding the index here, so my problem here is `naming` an index required? If so, does the image above gives a default name for an index if nothing is given by an `administrator`? And what it's default `name`?

Comment: The name (explicit or default) is needed only(?) for `DROP INDEX` and for reading `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `ALTER TABLE .. ADD INDEX` there is no requirement to add a name.

If you look at the [MySQL documentation for ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) you can see that the name parameter is optional (between square brackets), just like the type and options:

> | ADD {INDEX|KEY} [index_name]
>           [index_type] (index_col_name,...) [index_option] ...

When you add an index without specifying a name MySQL will generate a name based on the name of the first field in the index. If multiple indexes start with the same field the index name will be suffixed by a sequential number.

For example running this code:

```
CREATE TABLE `index_demo` (
  `IdField` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateField` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `GroupField` char(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `index_demo` ADD INDEX (`IdField`, `DateField`);

ALTER TABLE `index_demo` ADD INDEX (`IdField`, `GroupField`);
```

Will result in a table with 2 indexes, `IdField` and `IdField_2` as evidenced by the resulting create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `index_demo` (
  `IdField` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateField` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `GroupField` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `IdField` (`IdField`,`DateField`),
  KEY `IdField_2` (`IdField`,`GroupField`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Please note, the name parameter is only optional when using the `ALTER TABLE` syntax and not the `CREATE INDEX` syntax as again documented in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) (notice the lack of square brackets)

> CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name

I would however consider it a good practice to still name your indexes instead of relying on the default naming scheme.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is sure clarified my problems, `ALTER TABLE` = name parameter is optional and make a good practice to name the indexes.